# How can I grep hidden files?

Tags: grep, hidden-files, dotfiles

I am searching through a Git repository and would like to include the `.git` folder.

`grep` does not include this folder if I run

```
grep -r search *
```

What would be a grep command to include this folder?

Answer (score 170, accepted):

*Please refer to the solution at the end of this post as a better alternative to what you're doing.*

You can explicitly include hidden files (a directory is also a file).

```
grep -r search * .[^.]*
```

The `*` will match all files except hidden ones and `.[^.]*` will match only hidden files without `..`. However this will fail if there are either no non-hidden files or no hidden files in a given directory. You could of course explicitly add `.git` instead of `.*`.

However, if you simply want to search in a given directory, do it like this:

```
grep -r search .
```

The `.` will match the current path, which will include both non-hidden and hidden files.

Comment: The first approach (grep -r search * .*) worked for me. The second approach (grep -r search .) did not find the string. I found similar results when omitting the "-r" and searching the top-level directory only. I'm using GNU grep 2.6.3.

Comment: @Alan: That's weird. I use this regularly. Did you try it on the same directory?

Comment: Yes, I did. By the way, the results are the same whether I use tcsh or bash. It's a Debian 5 64-bit system, for what that's worth.

Comment: using `.*` will include the parent directory (because `..` matches)

Comment: What would be the correct command to grep the string `"func foobar("` in all `*.go` files, including files in a hidden subdirectory?

Comment: Is it safe to generalize about this solution as bahavior may vary between shells?

Comment: for the first version you should add --exclude-dir=.. to avoid searching in the parent folders

Comment: Not sure what my particular problem is, but when grepping (or using ack) through .classpath files in a large directory tree, I only get matches for the top level .classpath, even with the -r flag. I have not seen this particular behavior before. Can get it using find exec grep, but odd.

Answer (score 18):

I just ran into this problem, and based on @bitmask's answer, here is my simple modification to avoid the problem pointed out by @sehe:

```
grep -r search_string * .[^.]*
```

Comment: i do not get any results using this: `sudo grep -r ANDROID_HOME * .[^.]*` what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: @messerbill where are you running the search?

Comment: @bitmask was correct... this **was** a better answer, but they're now the same.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you will prefer to combine "grep" with the "find" command for a complete solution like:

```
find . -exec grep -Hn search {} \;
```

This command will search inside hidden files or directories for string "search" and list any files with a coincidence with this output format:

File path:Line number:line with coincidence

```
./foo/bar:42:search line
./foo/.bar:42:search line
./.foo/bar:42:search line
./.foo/.bar:42:search line
```

Comment: Pretty weird, but this is the only way I could recursively grep a large directory tree with a bunch of .classpath files.  Using all of the solutions above, grep (and ack for that matter), only return matches against the top-level .classpath file.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use this approach, assuming you're searching the current directory (otherwise replace . with the desired directory):

```
find . -type f | xargs grep search
```

or if you just want to search at the top level (which is quicker to test if you're trying these out):

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 | xargs grep search
```

UPDATE: I modified the examples in response to Scott's comments. I also added "-type f".

Comment: (1) `~` is the user’s home directory.  The question was not about the user’s home directory, so the answer should not mention `~`. (2) In a `find` command, ``-name '*'`` is a no-op (i.e., it serves no purpose).

Answer (score 2):

All the other answers are better. This one might be easy to remember:

```
find . -type f | xargs grep search
```

It finds only files (including hidden) and greps each file.

Comment: This is the best solution for my case

Answer (score 2):

To search within ONLY all hidden files and directories from your current location:

```
find . -name ".*" -exec grep -rs search {} \;
```

ONLY all hidden files:

```
find . -name ".*" -type f -exec grep -s search {} \;
```

ONLY all hidden directories:

```
find . -name ".*" -type d -exec grep -rs search {} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Tyler's suggestion, Here is the command to grep all files and folders recursively including hidden files

```sh
find . -name "*.*" -exec grep -li 'search' {} \;
```

Comment: this answer would be improved by using `-name "*" -type f` instead, if you only want to search inside files. The original suggestion will miss any files that do not have a type extension. This change will still recurse into hidden directories, but additionally skip running grep against directory objects.

Answer (score 1):

To find only within a certain folder you can use:

```
ls -al | grep " \."
```

It is a very simple command to list and pipe to grep.

Answer (score -1):

You can also search for specific types of hidden files like so for hidden directory files:

```
grep -r --include=*.directory "search-string"
```

This may work better than some of the other options. The other options that worked can be too slow.

Comment: Just like described above. You need to cd into the directory first and read the part "specific types of hidden files".

Comment: I do not understand what `--include=*.directory` is supposed to do - it's not like all my directories end in `.directory`?

Comment: No: those are hidden files in directories in Linux. Open a folder (which has an image set as a folder-icon for example) with your file explorer and show hidden files. There usually is a ".directory" file.

Comment: why the star then?

Comment: also, the question is specifically about `.git`, or including hidden directories in general