# using grep to check file content in hidden directory

Tags: bash, shell, maven, grep, sh

I have the following function in a shell script meant to handle some basic grep checks for a server setting in ~/.m2/settings.xml:

```
SETTINGS_FILE="~/.m2/settings.xml"
SETTINGS_SERVER_ID="<id>ossrh</id>"
check_settings () {
    echo grep "$1" "$SETTINGS_FILE"
    if grep -q  "$1" "$SETTINGS_FILE"; then
        echo "Server is set up...\n"; else
        echo "DEPLOY FAILED:\n\t$1 not found in ${SETTINGS_FILE}!
        fail "Fail :(";
    fi
    return 0
}
check_settings $SETTINGS_SERVER_ID
```

Unfortunately, this results in the following message:

```
grep <id>ossrh</id> ~/.m2/settings.xml
grep: ~/.m2/settings.xml: No such file or directory
DEPLOY FAILED:
    <id>ossrh</id> not found in ~/.m2/settings.xml!
Fail :(
```

Meanwhile, just using `grep "<id>ossrh</id>" ~/.m2/settings.xml` in the bash returns `<id>ossrh</id>`, which is expected.

I'm wondering if this is an issue of visibility- whether grep can see things in hidden directories (unlikely, considering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10375689/grep-hidden-files)) or whether it is an issue with the argument I'm passing grep (likely, considering how new I am to shell scripting)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `~/` prefix is not expanded to your home directory when the variable value is in quotes. Change the first line to:

```
SETTINGS_FILE=~/.m2/settings.xml
```

The clue to this is that the error message includes the `~` prefix. If the prefix had been expanded, the error message would have contained the absolute pathname to your directory.

Answer (score 4):

[Barmar's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24318203/2698019) answer is right, but you can also write it like this:

```
SETTINGS_FILE=~/'.m2/settings.xml'
```

This way you can include special characters and other stuff that should be quoted. Feel free to change single quotes to double quotes if you need to use a variable. (And I always prefer single quotes when there is no variable inside)

However, because you can also use `$HOME` instead of `~`, I would write it like this:

```
SETTINGS_FILE="$HOME/.m2/settings.xml"
```

Comment: @BroSlow but it is not going to work this way. Try it.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know the tilde only expanded when linked with a `/` or surrounded by whitespace. Learned something new, thanks/+1