# Where is the JAVA_HOME env variable set in MAC OS Yosemite

Tags: java, debugging, environment-variables, osx-yosemite, java-home

I have looked all over the system and cannot find where the $JAVA_HOME environmental variable is set. It is not on ~/.bash_profile or ~/.profile, also it is not on the ~/Library/LauncherAgents files, but if I type echo $JAVA_HOME I get:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home
```

So it is defined somewhere, but where? it is driving me crazy.

**UPDATE**

I was trying to install Maven, and had some problems, but not with the JAVA_HOME env variable, but still I added, just in case, the path to the Java directory to the .bash_profile file:

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/
```

Then I deleted it. And now whenever I try to print $JAVA_HOME I got nothing, it was like setting the variable in the bash_profile had an overriding effect wherever $JAVA_HOME was, so now everything is "normal". I mean, I need to declare the export statement for the $JAVA_HOME in the .bash_profile again to set Java. But before it didn't work like this, it was getting $JAVA_HOME from somewhere else !!!

Comment: Did you check `/Library/LaunchAgents` as well as `~/Library/LaunchAgents`?  Also check `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Yes both checked, I have the environment.plist on the ~/Library/LaunchAgents but it is not there ! I don't have the ~/.bashrc file by the way.

Comment: What about `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bashrc`?  Or `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` (though this is apparently not used in Yosemite).

Comment: Nothing there about JAVA_HOME.

Comment: `/etc/launchd.conf`? Or `/Library/LaunchDaemons` (not agents)?

Comment: Consider using http://www.jenv.be/ to manage multiple java instances on OSX machines.

Answer (score 0):

Find a list of files which include JAVA_HOME from the root directory:

```
cd /
find . -exec grep -Hn JAVA_HOME {} \;
```

**References**

- [How can I grep hidden files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10375689/1113772)
- [find(1) Mac OS X Manual Page](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html)